# Bootstrap misaligned label under textarea

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap form which consists of basic input fields and a few textarea's. Im using Django for my form validation and am having a persistent problem aligning validation labels under the textarea's. This form is only using bootstrap css modules so there is no custom css interfering with it as far as i can tell.

Example: The date and time field align perfectly as the notes validation label does not.
[image]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="well well-lg">
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="" autocomplete="off" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}      
                {% for field in UserForm %}     
                  <div class="form-group">  
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="{{ field.label }}"> {{ field.label }}</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">                                            
                             {{ field }}
                        </div>     
                         {% for error in field.errors %}
                                <div class="col-md-6">  
                                    <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>                                    
                                </div>            
                         {% endfor %}
                  </div>       
                {% endfor %} 
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you edit and add the generated template HTML code?

Comment: Just a tip. Dont put HTML tags to your controller. It will make it hard to edit some form objects. Just return error messages and values for form validation. In your case I dont see the `<input>` tag which made me think that you are generating them in your controller. That's a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

The number of columns inside the `class="row"` does not add up to [12](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). Try rewriting the `form-group` part like this:

```
<div class="form-group">  
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="{{ field.label }}"> {{ field.label }}</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    {{ field }}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
    <p>
      <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
    </p>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```